# For $\alpha\in(0^\circ;90^\circ)$ simplify $E=\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}-\frac{\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha}{\tan^2\alpha-1}$

Tags: trigonometry

For $\alpha\in(0^\circ;90^\circ)$ simplify $E=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}-\dfrac{\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha}{\tan^2\alpha-1}.$

My try: $E=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}-\dfrac{\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha}{\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha}}=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}-\dfrac{\sin\alpha\cdot\cos^2\alpha+\cos^3\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha}.$ Is there a better approach? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Correct.You can continue. Use the formula $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$

Comment: Thank you! I see it now.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}-\dfrac{\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha}{\tan^2\alpha-1}=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}-\dfrac{\cos^2\alpha(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)}{\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha}=$$
$$=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}-\dfrac{\cos^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}=\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha.$$